# Linux sendmail spam?

Tags: email, spam, sendmail

I have a linux server with sendmail doing spam filtering for some years. We usually do  filtering spam by using spamcop, spamhaus, njabl but we dont seem to keep up. The number of spam mail getting through is rising.

Do you having any better alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out SMFS for mail spam and virus filtering that works with sendmail. It includes:

- smf-clamd - Sendmail ClamAV milter
- smf-spamd - Sendmail SpamAssassin milter
- smf-zombie - Sendmail Zombie SPAM Blocker
- smf-spf - Sendmail SPF milter
- smf-grey - Sendmail GreyList milter
- smf-sav - Sendmail Sender Address Validator

Project homepage:
http://smfs.sourceforge.net/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Running spamd, and spambayes for bayesian filtering is probably the best you're going to get. It however requires getting samples of spam and ham from your end users.

Answer (score 1):

[amavisd-new](http://www.ijs.si/software/amavisd/) has support for [sendmail as a milter](http://www.ijs.si/software/amavisd/#features-mta).  We've used it for years in a Postfix setup and it's been pretty good.  It acts as a "framework" that draws in multiple spam-detection systems, such as pyzor, spamassassin, etc., and supports pattern matching (should you need it).